# Is there any way to check pc monitor without restarting

Tags: display

Is there any way to check pc monitor without restarting? Or keyboard combinations to know whether is PC monitor is working or not.

Comment: Check it for what?

Comment: My second monitor is not working again.
I have been unplugging and replugging it in the past few days, no problem.
But this morning, after I unplugged, and then replug, it would not come on.
When I plug it, PC makes a sound, which means it is recognized.

Comment: You shouldn't have to "restart" your machine to "get it working" just extend the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You could first try checking your display settings (right click on desktop, hit display settings) and see if the other monitor is detected that way. Another option would be to check Device Manager for additional displays. If you don't see it here, I would suggest you check the cabling or try hooking the monitor up to another PC.